# How to route group to queue to specific yarn queue via ambari?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I can sucessfully route a user to a specific queue using ambari. The syntax I use for a user is:

```
u:hive:prod
```

However, I cannot manage to do it for a group.

The syntax I use for a group is:

```
g:datascience:dev
```

On the edge node, I have a a group called `datascience` containing the user `scientist`

```
$ groups scientist
scientist : scientist datascience
```

When I send a beeline command with this user (say, `insert into default.routingtest values (0, "test")`), I have the following error message:

> INFO  : Dag submit failed due to
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Failed to submit
>   application application_1592385599162_0001 submitted by user scientist
>   reason: No groups found for user scientist
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.placement.UserGroupMappingPlacementRule.getPlacementForApp(UserGroupMappingPlacementRule.java:210)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.placement.PlacementManager.placeApplication(PlacementManager.java:67)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.placeApplication(RMAppManager.java:791)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.createAndPopulateNewRMApp(RMAppManager.java:368)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.submitApplication(RMAppManager.java:320)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ClientRMService.submitApplication(ClientRMService.java:645)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:277)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationClientProtocol$ApplicationClientProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationClientProtocol.java:563)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:524)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1025)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:876)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:822)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2682)

What is causing this error and how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the user and the group did not exist on all the machine of the cluster. Make sure user and group do exist on all machines.